# Zooming Bitmap after drawing on it?

Tags: android, bitmap, zooming

I'am doing FFT processing on .wav signal and draw it on Bitmap.

How it looks, when it is finished:

[image: picture of my fft]

Is there any way to zoom this picture?

Comment: is the bitmap applied to a view or canvas?

Comment: Bitmap is applied to canvas.

Comment: well I might apply that bitmap to an ImageView if possible to handle scaling.. there are even some pinch zoom imageview classes out there for android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some codes from my old projects which needs also scaling in onDraw, they might help you or not.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    ....
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

    mIcon.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```